# Json file that would be used in Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I want to know, if the Json files that would be used in Elasticsearch should have a predefined structure. Or can any Json document can be uploaded?

I've seen some Json documents that before each record there's such:

```
{"index":{"_index":"plos","_type":"article","_id":0}}
{"id":"10.1371/journal.pone.0007737","title":"Phospholipase C-β4 Is Essential for the Progression of the Normal Sleep Sequence and Ultradian Body Temperature Rhythms in Mice"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you can upload any JSON document. However, be mindful that Elasticsearch can create/change the index mapping based on your create/update actions. So if you send a JSON that includes a previously unknown field? Congratulations, your index mapping now contains a new field! In this same way the data type of a field might also be affected by introducing a document with data of a different type. So, my advice is be very careful in constructing your requests to avoid surprises.

Fyi, the syntax you posted looks like a bulk request (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html). Those do have some demands on the syntax to clarify what you want to do to which documents. "Index" call sending one document is very unrestricted though.

Comment: You may also want to look at the dynamic configuration options for elasticsearch if you don't want your index getting out of hand with varying requests: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html